# I am trying to disable a button if a condition met using ajax. but it is not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, express-handlebars

I am trying to disable a button if a condition met using ajax . But it is not working .

```js
function changeQuantity(cartId, productId, count) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/change-product-quantity',
        data: {
            cart: cartId,
            product: productId,
            count: count
        },
        method: 'post',
        beforeSend: function() {
            // disable your button here
            if (count <= 1) {
                ("#btn").prop("disabled", true);
            } else {
                ("#btn").prop("disabled", false)
            }
        },
        success: (response) => {
            alert(response)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: You're ignoring the returned data and just using the `count` that was passed in to `changeQuantity`. Did you mean to set the button status in the `success` function?

Comment: Please also add `browser console logs` to your question

Answer (score 1):

Your code is missing the $ selector before `("#btn")`. This is necessary for selecting the button with jQuery. Corrected code:

```
function changeQuantity(cartId, productId, count) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/change-product-quantity',
        data: {
            cart: cartId,
            product: productId,
            count: count
        },
        method: 'post',
        beforeSend: function() {
            // disable your button here
            if (count <= 1) {
                $("#btn").prop("disabled", true);
            } else {
                $("#btn").prop("disabled", false)
            }
        },
        success: (response) => {
            alert(response)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the **beforeSend** event handler is called before the AJAX request is sent, but the **disable()** method of the button element only takes effect after the request is sent.

To fix this, you need to move the **disable()** method call to the success event handler. This way, the button will be disabled after the request is sent and the response is received.

And also you forgot the $ in your code

Here is the code:

```
function changeQuantity(cartId, productId, count) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/change-product-quantity',
    data: { cart: cartId, product: productId, count: count },
    method: 'post',
    success: (response) => {
      alert(response);
      // disable your button here
      if (count <= 1) {
        $("#btn").prop("disabled", true);
      } else {
        $("#btn").prop("disabled", false);
      }
    }
  });
}
```